# ResourceNotFoundException when creating activity view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Below mentioned is the method that contains sum bug due to which i am getting ResourceNotFoundException whenever i am trying to start the activity.

```
private void createActivityLayout(Fragment fragment) 
{
    FrameLayout frameLayout =  new FrameLayout(this);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int padding_5dp = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f); 

    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    frameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_border);

    frameLayout.setPadding(padding_5dp, padding_5dp, padding_5dp, padding_5dp);

    frameLayout.setClickable(true);

    **int id = IdGenerator.getId();

    frameLayout.setId(id);

    String tag = fragment.getTag() != null ? fragment.getTag() : "Tag-".concat(Integer.toString(IdGenerator.getId()));

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id, fragment, tag).commit();**

    childFrames.put(((NoteFragment)fragment).getNoteFragmentId(), frameLayout);

    updateActivityView();
}
```

According to me the problem could be present in the bold code above. IdGenerator.getId() method simply generates a random integer for unique ids.

Below mentioned is the exception message that i am getting in LogCat in eclipse.
The resource id mentioned in the exception below changes each time i run the application.

```
**04-13 02:01:21.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gp.app.professionalpa/com.gp.app.layout.manager.NotesLayoutManagerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x323660**
```

Comment: What if you try adding the frame layout first to your activity layout, and only after choose it as a container for the fragment?

Comment: Post some more of the Logcat statements.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you define an id in the values folder ? create an xml file in values folder with the name "ids" and place the below xml in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="some_name" type="id"></item>
</resources>
```

then you can refer to that id and set it like below

```
frameLayout.setId(R.id.some_name);
```

I think this would help you if setting id is the problem.

Comment: what in case i have a large number of framelayouts in my activity. and the framelayout can be added or removed dynamically. How i can i use the above mentioned strategy in this case. Thanks